# UI Automation of CefSharp window not possible

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation, cefsharp, ui-spy

I'm trying to make CefSharp window accessible with MS UI Automation tools like inspect.exe or UISpy.
By default the CefSharp windows is treated by these as an image and the UI properties are inaccessible.

I've set the commandline argument "force-renderer-accessibility". Itself it didn't change anything, but then I added this code:

```
browser.AccessibilityHandler = new AccessibilityHandler(browser);
browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    if ((bool)args.NewValue)
    {
        browser.GetBrowserHost().SetAccessibilityState(CefState.Enabled);
    }
};
```

It partially worked, I can access most of the controls, but some of them are still inaccessible (they are referred to by UISpy as 'group' and you can't traverse them deeper as tree nodes). Also the scan finds some items a bit away from their real position.

Is there a better way to make CefSharp WPF window available to UI automation tools? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

I'm using CefSharp 97.1.12

Comment: Your welcome to submit a PR with improvements. Otherwise you can switch to https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.Wpf.HwndHost#cefsharpwpfhwndhost

Comment: Issue https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2053 is used to track accessibility support in the WPF implementation, the current implementation likely needs improvements. Someone from the community will need to get involved in making those improvements.

Comment: @amaitland I understand it's not fully working and its experimental right now. There is no CefSharp.Wpf.HwndHost version that supports .net framework 461, right?

Comment: .net 4.6.2 is the minimum. 462 much better support for per monitor DPI awareness.